# Python function input

Tags: python, function, arguments

i want to set the output of a function as the input of the other function,
like this

```
def math(a,b):
some code...
return(a,b,c)

def pro(a,b,c):
some code
return(e)
#and then call function by:
pro(math(a,b))
```

however,

> TypeError: pro() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'

Can you tell me how can i change my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use asterisk:

```
pro(*math(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the returned value as the arguments:

```
args = math(3, 4) # returns (a, b, c)
print pro(*args) # pro(a, b, c)
```